# How to convert PowerBI Dash to Tableau

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, tableau-api

I have a PowerBI dashboard that I am trying to convert into Tableau but am having troubles. The Data source in PowerBI that I am using is a table that I do not have in my database. Is there a way get this data source from PowerBI to make available to Tableau? I have 3.5 Million rows in this data source so I know pasting to excel isn't an option because excel maxes out at ~1.5 Million rows. This is for an internship and I have no direction and am utterly confused as I have no experience with either of these software. THANKS!

Have tried copy paste to excel with the table in PowerBI but no luck. The table being used isn't available in my database so I can't just use it in Tableau and the PowerBI that I am using is a PowerBI file so I don't even know where it is getting its data source?

Comment: I'm not a user of PowerBI, so I don't know the possibilities. But could you export/copy-paste to a csv-file? You can import the csv/text-file in Tableau and it's not limited to a number of rows like Excel.

Comment: I did in fact end up doing this as I didn't have access to the table or view from a database. a simple export of the data as a csv allowed me to use the same data I had visualized in PBI as a datasource in Tableau. Another coworker also suggested I could check if Tableau supports XMLA connections, which I could then have Tableau look at the PBI file directly. Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: You can download a free tool called "DAX studio". It allows you to connect to power BI files directly and see/export data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Notepad and save it as a .csv file and then connect to it in your Tableau Workbook as a  -> More -> CSV. If you are publishing your Tableau Workbook with the embedded data source from a shared network drive, others will be able to use the data.